# Regras de nasalidade em vogais seguidas por "m" e "n"

Tags: pronúncia

Em algumas palavras as vogais seguidas por “m” ou “n” não são nasalizadas (s**e**mana, b**o**nito). Na palavra “banana”, o primeiro “a” não é nasalizado, mas o segundo é (“ban**ã**na”), apesar de ambos serem seguidos por um “n”.

Também existem palavras onde ambas pronúncias são aceitáveis: “c**a**marão” ou “c**ã**marão”; “J**a**neiro” ou ”J**ã**neiro”.

E finalmente palavras onde a vogal pode pode ser ou não nasalizadas dependendo do significado: “c**ã**minha” (diminutivo de “cama”) ou “c**a**minha” (do verbo “caminhar”)

Quais são as regras de nasalidade em vogais seguidas por “m” e “n”?

Comment: Os teus exemplos sugerem que as vogais tónicas são nasaladas. *Cãminha* será por causa de *c**ã**ma*? Aplica-se a outros diminutivos, *paninho, gominha, caninha?* Tou só a especular. Aqui em Portugal nada disso é nasalado. Pelo menos no meu sotaque não é; se no de outras pessoas é, eu nem noto.

Comment: Não acho que tenha uma regra. No caso de *banana*, ouço das duas formas: *banãna* e *bãnãna*, depende do sotaque como lembrado pelo Jacinto. Isso também vale para o verbo caminhar. [Pronúncias da palavra *Banana*](https://pt.forvo.com/word/banana/#pt)

Comment: Talvez estes artigos ajudem numa possível resposta: [A nasalidade das vogais em Português](https://www.e-publicacoes.uerj.br/index.php/soletras/article/viewFile/4717/3480) e [Uma Análise Acústica das Vogais Orais, Nasais e Nasalizadas no Dialeto de Vitória da Conquista, Bahia](http://www.uel.br/revistas/uel/index.php/signum/article/view/13068)

Answer (score 1):

Não existe pronúncia correcta.

Há gente que diz *Ban**ã**na*; e há gente que diz *B**ã**n**ã**na*. Essas variações há em outras palavras. No Brasil, há *"Tumatche"*, *"Tómatche"*, *"Tumati"* etc. Há também *"mulher"*, *"mulhere"*, *"mulherl"* (interior de São Paulo), *"mulé"*. Então é coisa que se modifica a depender da região.

Answer (score 0):

Quando a consoante nasal está na sílaba seguinte, não creio que o fenômeno possa ser chamado de nasalização. A pronúncia corrente não é /banãna/, mas /banɐna/.

A regra geral é que ocorre na sílaba tônica, ou, no caso de palavras derivadas, na sílaba que corresponde à tônica na palavra primitiva.

Assim, /banɐna/ e não /bɐnɐna/. E, no caso de "caminha", diminutivo de cama, /kɐminha/ porque vem de "cama" - /kɐma/, onde /kɐ/ é a sílaba tônica.

Se entendermos que não é uma nasalisação, então o caso é análogo ao das sílabas tônicas em "e" e "o" seguidas de "m" ou "n", em que a vogal é sempre fechada.

Quando a consoante nasal está na mesma sílaba, ela opera como índice de nasalização, que, no caso, é obrigatória: "campo" - /kãpo/, "quente", "som", "findo", "cúmplice", etc, todas com vogal nasal.

Evidentemente há variação regional na pronúncia, e é diferente em PT/PT, mas a norma culta falada do PT/BR é essa.